# Angular 5 - Api call with header does not work

Tags: angular, .net-core, postman

I'm passing three new variables to the api call headers.

Interceptor.ts

```
const authReq = request.clone({
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'ACCESS':  this.user.access,
              'ID': this.user.id,
              'PROFILE': this.user.profile
            })
});
```

Specifically, it fails me exclusively, the PROFILE variable, the api, returns an empty array.

If I delete the PROFILE variable it works correctly for me.

I have tried to use  Postman and the same thing happens to me.

The value of the PROFILE variable is "ADMIN" and it doesn't work, but if I put any other value it works perfectly again.

It's a GET call:

Example of GET (Net Core) method:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public ActionResult<List<UserDto>> AllUsers()
{
    try
    {
        return bluser.getListUsers();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log_BL.Error(ex, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType.Name + " - " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of adding these headers. Are you doing some sort of auth check with Authentication Schemes in .net core??

Comment: They will be added in the future, but at the moment in the "Net Core" app they are not used.

Comment: _I have tried to use Postman and the same thing happens to me_ - then it doesn't look like an Angular problem, but like an API/backend problem.

Comment: I think the same, I think it's something in the Api

Comment: It has to be some issue at the backend. Do yoy have any Authorize attributes to your end points??

Comment: The problem is in the api, in a filter of a dll, I will eliminate this question because it does not help anyone and I do not have access to see the solution, thanks

Comment: The problem was in an attribute of a model / dto, it filtered by that attribute and did not interpret the headers well